# How to integrate p(x)*f(x) where p(x) is a polynomial and f(x) is a function? MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, numerical-integration, polynomials

I want to integrate p(x)*f(x) where p(x) is a polynomial and f(x) is a function. I am working in MATLAB.
I have the coefficients of the polynomial in a vector.

```
p=[2,3,4,5];
funct=@(x) xˆ2;
```

I know how to integrate the function by itself, as well as how to integrate the polynomial by itself. However, I just can't find any info on how to take the integral of the product.

Here is what I tried:

```
p2=poly2sym(p)
integral(funct*p2,-1,1)
```

but p2 is not a function handle.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `p2` is not a function handle – it's a symbolic expression, but [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) performs *numerical* integration and requires a function handle that returns floating point values. Even if `p2` was a function handle, multiply function handles (e.g., `funct*p2`) is not valid. Additionally, `funct` needs to be vectorized.

Instead of [`poly2sym`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/poly2sym.html), you can evaluate your integral numerically with [`polyval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html) like this:

```
p = [2,3,4,5];
funct = @(x)x.^2;                  % use element-wise power to vectorize
p2 = @(x)polyval(p,x);
integral(@(x)funct(x).*p2(x),-1,1) % evaluate two handles into one
```

which returns `4.533333333333333`. Or you could compute this particular integral symbolically using [`int`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html):

```
p = [2,3,4,5];
syms x;
funct = x^2;
p2 = poly2sym(p,x);
int(funct*p2,x,-1,1)
```

which returns the exact rational value of `68/15` (use [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) or [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) to convert to decimal or floating point, respectively).